# Optimized webpack bundle depending on browser and browser version?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I know webpack serves say a bundle.js, which has all the Babel transpilation from ECMA2015, jsx and stuff to ECMA5. This file is n times bigger than the original one to be compatible with any browser. But some browsers have support for lot of the transpiled features, so in those case the extra download/run volume is a waste. Do you know if webpack has any ability to serve/create different bundles optimized for any browser/versions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create different bundles, but how would you serve them? Usually bundles are pre-build and not in the fly, so what you are asking should be done in the fly based on browser. One way I can think of right now close to what you are asking is use nodeJS to serve different pre-build bundles on GET bundle.js based on User-agent. Perhaps someone else have other ideas though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@babel/preset-env`, which is exactly for avoiding unnecessary polyfills. Keep Chrome 41 so as to let google indexer crawl your app properly.
`useBuiltIns` does the trick.

You can uncomment debug line to see what is going on.

in your .babelrc, just add

```
{ "presets": [
          ["@babel/preset-env", { 
                //"debug": true, 
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "> 1%",
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "chrome 41",
                        "ie >= 9",
                        "safari >= 7"
                    ]
                },
            "useBuiltIns": 'usage'
          }]
]}
```